# Inline Javascript not loading on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser

I am working on Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM Portals, but despite that I am trying to include a [Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) modal when pressing a button.

***It works on most browsers (Chrome, Firefox & Edge)*** but in Internet Explorer 11.

This is the entire code I am trying to deploy:

```
<a href="#" id="searchHelp">
    <img border="0" src="http://some.url" alt="?" width="15" height="15">
</a>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript">
console.log("Javascript loaded");
var helpButton = document.querySelector('#searchHelp');

if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf(".NET") >= 0) {
    console.log('Triggered IE Modal actions');
    helpButton.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
        e.returnValue = false;
        loadModal();
    });
} else {
    console.log('Triggered non-IE Modal actions');
    helpButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadModal();
    }, false)
}

function loadModal() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open( "GET", "http://some.url/to-load", false); 

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4) {
            xhr.onreadystatechange = null;
            if(this.status == 200) {
                var parser = new DOMParser(),
                    content = parser.parseFromString(this.response, "text/html"),
                    form = content.querySelector('#liquid_form');

                swal({
                    icon: "info",
                    content: form,
                    button: {
                        text: "Close",
                        value: false,
                        visible: true,
                        className: "",
                        closeModal: true,
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
</script>
<style>
    .swal-modal {
        width: 90% !important;
    }
    .swal-content {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

The modal works great on all the browsers I mentioned before but no action is fired when clicking on the button. It goes to the top of the page and a hashtag is added to the URL. The message "Javascript loaded" is not being displayed either.

I've tried to increase browser compatibility: I've changed `fetch()` to `XMLHttpRequest` and added browser verification by testing on the Developer Tools console , added `attachEvent()` and `addEventListener()`. I did try also to include `type="javascript"` on the tag. Any clues?

Comment: IE11 does not support arrow => functions, using them conditionally isn't going to work as it can't parse them.

Comment: Alex, according to what I understand, on IE it won't reach that arrow function.

Comment: But it still needs to be able to parse all of the JavaScript initially, before it executes it. It sees "=>" and has no idea what to do with it so aborts with a syntax error (you should see this in the error console).

Comment: You could try switching it to `helpButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadModal();
    }, false);` and see if it works properly on IE because it will still work on the other browsers.

Comment: Okay ALek, it seems to work. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE11 does not support `=>` arrow functions, using them conditionally isn't going to work as even though execution won't reach them in your current code, taken as a whole the JavaScript is unparsable by an non-ES6 compliant browser like IE.

Switch to the traditional `function(e) { ... }` syntax.

Comment: As already commented, this works. Thank you. I hope there is a way to standarize ES6 for all browsers soon, but I guess this is a long way.